# How to write algorithm given a runtime

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm currently taking an algorithm analysis course. One of the questions of a quiz was to write an algorithm with the runtime `T(n) = 4T(3n/4) + n^2` where the algorithm does not have to do anything significant.

I couldn't find any similar examples so I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify how to think about this kind of problem, just use an array of `n` elements to represent a problem of size `n`.

Then, the running time `T(n)` represents the algorithm run on the array.

The running time `4T(3n/4)` represents the algorithm run on 3 quarters of the array four times.

The running time `n^2` represents some quadratic operation on the array (for example, a bubble sort).

```
silly_algo (arr[], n)
    if n == 0 return
    for i : 1..4
        silly_algo(arr, 3*n/4)
    bubblesort(arr, n)
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. Thank you.